# Is it possible to bind an django-user account to one specific workstation?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

My goal is that every user can only log in to my Django web app from a specific workstation.

If the user tries to log in from another workstation, the login should be denied.

Is it possible to implement such a licensing model in Django, possibly via identifying the hostname of the workstation?

I'm using Django 1.10/Python 3.5.

Comment: I'd use a client certificate. Only install that certificate on the specific workstation, identify by the certificate.

Comment: This was my first thought, but nothing prevents the user from simply installing the certificate on other workstations.

Comment: What kind of workstations are we talking about? It depends on the OS if they can even re-export the private key (the crucial component in the whole scheme).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identifying a workstation by IP address or other means that is available over HTTP only is very error prone and not reliable.  Instead, I'd require that the user installs a [client certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client_certificate) that you have generated.

This assumes you can control the installation of a certificate (there are two parts, a private key and the certificate itself), so you can make sure the certificate is installed on just one workstation. Your installer can do the verification here, as it has can gather much more information about the workstation, running locally.

Once a certificate is installed, you'd need to verify this. Have the *front-end server* do this, NGINX for example has [full support for handling certificate exchange and validation](http://nategood.com/client-side-certificate-authentication-in-ngi), passing you the DN or even the full certificate for your app (Django) to use in the authorisation. See https://github.com/kimvais/django-ssl-client-auth for a project that lets you handle NGINX-verified certificate information.

On Windows and OS X, private keys can be imported as 'non-exportable'. This flag can still be circumvented, but no software licensing scheme is unbreakable. Make sure you have a proper licensing in place, log host information (IP addresses, user agent strings, etc.) and if you see the same cert being used from multiple IP addresses or have other proof that they are using the certificate from more than one machine, terminate the license and revoke the certificate. In other words: take reasonable precautions, make it harder to willingly break your license, and when they do anyway, you have grounds to revoke the license.